# How can I auto-populate QuickCreate form fields with data from a parent record using a jscript OnLoad event?

Tags: dynamics-crm, jscript, webresource

When a user sets the "Scope" on an Opportunity record to "Parent Opportunity", a grid appears that allows the user to create child Opportunity records associated with the parent.  I am trying to create a web resource for an OnLoad event that will auto-populate the Opportunity Name, Contact, and Account of the QuickCreate form with the data that is in the Parent Opportunity form.  Account and Contact are lookups to separate entities, and Opportunity Name is a text field.  Here is what I have so far:

```
function SetLocalStorage(executionContext)
{

var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
var account = formContext.getControl("ParentAccountId").getAttribute().getValue();
var contact = formContext.getControl("ParentContactId").getAttribute().getValue();
var oppname = formContext.getControl("new_name").getAttribute().getValue();

localStorage.setItem("Account", account);
localStorage.setItem("Contact", contact);
localStorage.setItem("OpportunityName", oppname);

}
```

I am fairly new to JavaScript and am not really sure what to add to the web resource in order for the QuickCreate form to auto-populate.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose Codeless solution. Dynamics 365 already provides out of box feature for the same requirement.

For sake of explanation, I have taken Account and Contact Entity.

So from Account If I want to create Contact, few of information shall be autopopulated as shown in Image below.

[image]

Now how do I do this. There is 1:N relationship from Account to Contact. So in your case there will be 1:N relationship from Opportunity to Scope. Just like below image

[image]

Now when you go inside relationship you will have mapping. What this mapping does it copy data from Source to Target fields. In my case I have few fields been mapped from Account to contact. You can do the same and this will solve your issue.

[image]

Comment: "Scope" is an option set field in my Opportunity entity, it is not a separate entity.  Will this still work if there is no relationship?

Comment: Scope is just a trigger in your case to show grid. What is important for us is entity in grid. I mean grid will show or create a record for a entity(I believe it is child opportunity) entity in your case. This is the relationship which is of our interest child opportunity entity related to opportunity

Comment: I understand now.  Your solution worked.  Thank you!!
I do have one more question related to this: Will creating these mappings affect previously created 'Child Opportunity' records?  I do not want that to happen.  I'm hoping it'll only auto-populate fields for new records being created, is this correct?

Comment: cool!! It worked.
Yes it will affect only newly created records.
Could you please mark it as solved, will help others as well.